# What tags should be used for graph-related and Graph[]-related questions?

Tags: discussion, tagging, retagging

**EDIT: Be sure to check the update at the end of this post!**

---

I propose we never use the tag [graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) on this site.  It is too confusing, and people will keep using it for both [graphs (as in vertices and edges)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29), and for plotting.

I've been following that tag on SO for a while, and it's an awful mess of a mix of plotting, graph theory and the Facebook graph API.

---

So what shall we use?  It has been proposed we use [graph-theory](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) instead.  I think this sounds too much like mathematics, and it's not appropriate for [questions like this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226/how-to-export-and-import-graphs-with-additional-data).

I propose using [graphs-networks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs-networks) for this, [which is also what WRI calls the new domain area added to Mathematica 8](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphsAndNetworks.html).

I don't have a strong opinion on *which* tag we should use (except that I think it's important to banish the ambiguous [graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) from here).  But I very strongly wish that we agree on a standard, encourage using it, and retag the existing questions appropriately.

Note: I care about this because I've used Mathematica's new `Graph[]`-related functionality a lot, and I want to be able to find relevant questions without noise from discussions about plotting.  I also wish we have a single central tag for this (no fragmentation).

---

**Update**

To avoid confusion, this question is about this thing:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is **not** about this thing:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is in fact about making sure that the two will never get mixed under the same tag, and also that it'll be easy to find all `Graph[]`-related and graph-theory-related posts in the future.

---

**To get this rolling, please post tag name-suggestions as answers, and please vote (up or down) on existing answers!**

I will post [graphs-and-networks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs-and-networks) as a suggestion, and I recommend someone else post [graph-theory](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) as this came up too.

I suggest we choose one based on these criteria:

- It should be appropriate for questions related to `Graph[]` in any way
- It should be appropriate for questions related to [graph-theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory)
- It should be appropriate for these existing questions:

  - [How to export and import Graphs with additional data?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226/how-to-export-and-import-graphs-with-additional-data)
  - [How to create regular (planar) graphs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43/planar-graph-creation)
- It should be appropriate for these sample questions (feel free to suggest others):

  - How do I transfer graphs created in [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) to Mathematica?
  - How do I implement an algorithm for finding connected components?
  - How do I highlight in red one group of nodes in a bipartite graph?
  - How do I generate a random graph with a given degree distribution?
  - Why do `AtomQ@Graph[x]` and `AtomQ@Graph[{}]` return different results?
  - Why does `MatchQ[Graph[{1->2}], Graph[___]]` return `False`?

If you do not agree that it is preferable to have a single tag covering all these, please explain why in an answer.

Comment: Could you use `Graph[]` as a tag? Or otherwise Graph-function or something to that extent, to clarify that it is a mma function, and not a plot or math problem.

Comment: @insect No, tags must be lowercase, and I think they shouldn't have `[]` (not sure).  Also, `Graph[]` is not really a function, in fact it can be an atomic object (in the `AtomQ` sense)

Comment: [tag:graph-plotting] and [tag:graph-theory] sound like a good idea to me. Not sure what exactly a *graph-network* is supposed to be.

Comment: @David [tag:graph-plotting] is ambiguous too.  Is it about visualizing graphs, or about making plots? ([tag:plotting] is fine for the latter).  Also, do you think [tag:graph-theory] is appropriate for a question about how to import a graph from e.g. the [Pajek format](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/pajek/)?  It's good that you note that [tag:graphs-networks] (note the `s` at the end) is unfamiliar to you.  Is [tag:graphs-and-networks] confusing too (note the documentation centre uses the same)?

Comment: Of course if most people say that [tag:graph-theory] is the best solution, even for questions about handling a [network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_science) on a computer, then we can go with that by me.

Comment: Well, graphs-and-networks has the downside of being ambiguous again for both plotting and the mathematical side. Maybe both tags, graphs-and-networks and plotting, should be used together for graph plotting questions?

Answer (score 7):

I propose using [graphs-and-networks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs-and-networks) as a general tag for this purpose.  [The documentation centre uses this exact title](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphsAndNetworks.html).  Anyone working in network science will instantly recognize what it is about.  It would come up as a tag suggestion when starting to type `graph...`, which is what people asking about graphs are likely to do.

I do not know if this is instantly recognizable for a mathematician working in graph-theory.

Comment: +1: Do this, make [tag:graph-theory] a synonym of it.

Comment: @Isaac Do you know what is the procedure for creating a synonym?  They have to be requested from moderators on meta?

Comment: I think that, unless there are existing questions with the relevant tags and users with sufficiently-many upvotes in those tags, a moderator has to manually do it.  (I think users with enough upvotes in a tag can propose synonyms or maybe can propose that the tag should be a synonym for something else, and other users with enough upvotes can vote for/against the synonym until it reaches a certain + or – score to become a synonym or be removed from the proposed list.)

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion was [graph-theory](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory).  I am posting it here so people can vote on it.